# Python - feed an object with a list

Tags: python, list, object, arguments, feed

So I have the following code, which merges two text files (strings) into a list. This list should then feed an object.

> cat file1.txt

```
['2.02', '-3.88', '15.25']
['4.40', '-2.36', '14.97']
['5.44', '0.34', '7.34']
['5.76', '0.41', '7.60']
['5.35', '0.19', '13.95']
```

> cat file2.txt

```
['P1']
['P2']
['P3']
['P4']
['P5']
```

> Code

```
from ast import literal_eval

#combine both files and return a list
def combiner(infile1, infile2):
    with open(infile1) as f1, open(infile2) as f2:
        f1_lists = (literal_eval(line) for line in f1)
        f2_lists = (literal_eval(line) for line in f2)
        for l1, l2 in zip(f1_lists, f2_lists):
            l3 = l1 + l2
            return l3


class Compass:

def __init__(self, coordx, coordy, coordz, positivity):
        self.coordX = coordx
        self.coordY = coordy
        self.coordZ = coordz
        self.posit = posit

def main():
    file1 = "file1.txt"
    file2 = "file2.txt"
    args = combiner(file1, file2)
    c = Compass(*args)
    print c.coordX + ' ' + c.coordY + ' ' + c.coordZ + ' ' + c.posit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> output

```
2.02 - 3.88 15.25 P1
```

It outputs just the first list of course. How would you do to keep feeding until the list is over? 
Maybe using the lines from the file1.txt?

Comment: Please give an example of the output you're looking for.
Also everything in a class needs to be indented to be part of the class

Comment: The reason for your output is you are returning from function as soon as you get first value with `return l3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are returning only the first line from a list from `combiner()`. Solution of this is to make a list l3, and then keep appending to it the new lines and return it after the loop has exhausted.

The second problem is that you have 5 coordinates and positivities, therefore you also need 5 instances of `Compass`. Solution of this is to create a list of instances.

Solving the above problems, your code will look like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

#combine both files and return a list
def combiner(infile1, infile2):
    with open(infile1) as f1, open(infile2) as f2:
        l3 = [] # this is a list for storing all the lines from both files
        f1_lists = (literal_eval(line) for line in f1)
        f2_lists = (literal_eval(line) for line in f2)
        for l1, l2 in zip(f1_lists, f2_lists):
            l3.append(l1 + l2)
        return l3 # Return all the lines from both text files


class Compass:

    def __init__(self, coordx, coordy, coordz, positivity):
            self.coordX = coordx
            self.coordY = coordy
            self.coordZ = coordz
            self.posit = positivity

def main():
    file1 = "file1.txt"
    file2 = "file2.txt"
    args = combiner(file1, file2)
    # You have 5 different Compass coordinates, therefore you need 5 different Compass instances
    # Therefore make a list of Compass instances
    compasslist = [ Compass(args[i][0], args[i][1], args[i][2], args[i][3]) for i in range(len(args))]

    # args[i][0] is coordx of i-th line (file1.txt), args[i][1] is coordy of i-th line (file1.txt),
    # args[i][2] is coordz of i-th line (file1.txt), and args[i][3] is positivity of i-th line (file2.txt)

    # Lets print all the Compass instances
    for i in range(len(args)):
        print compasslist[i].coordX + ' ' + compasslist[i].coordY + ' ' + compasslist[i].coordZ + ' ' + compasslist[i].posit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: perfect! Your additional list of instance was very practtical.     Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a note, check ,Alakazam suggestion doesnt instantiate more objects, but rather use the same inside the loop for.   Any advantages?

Comment: I could do it without creating a list of ```Compass``` instances, but what if I need them in the future? 
Since you aren't creating list of instances, you can only have 1 instance. And after the loop, you can only access the last instance. So the first 4 instances are gone

Answer (score 1):

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open(filename) as infile_1, open(filename2) as infile_2:  #Open Both files
    for a, b in zip(infile_1, infile_2):                       #Read each line in parallel
        val =  literal_eval(a) + literal_eval(b)
        print(", ".join(val))
```

**Output:**

```
2.02, -3.88, 15.25, P1
4.40, -2.36, 14.97, P2
5.44, 0.34, 7.34, P3
5.76, 0.41, 7.60, P4
5.35, 0.19, 13.95, P5
```

Comment: thank you. This suggestion generates a huge list which  can not be used to feed the object, since it accepts onle 4 args.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning l3 at the first iteration of your loop, that's why you only get a line in output.

```
from ast import literal_eval

#combine both files and return a list
def combiner(infile1, infile2):
    with open(infile1) as f1, open(infile2) as f2:
        f1_lists = (literal_eval(line) for line in f1)
        f2_lists = (literal_eval(line) for line in f2)

        result = [] # Store the results in a list
        for l1, l2 in zip(f1_lists, f2_lists):
            l3 = l1 + l2
            result.append(l3)
        return result # Return the list


class Compass:

    def __init__(self, coordx, coordy, coordz, positivity):
            self.coordX = coordx
            self.coordY = coordy
            self.coordZ = coordz
            self.posit = positivity

def main():
    file1 = "file1.txt"
    file2 = "file2.txt"
    all_args = combiner(file1, file2)
    for args in all_args: 
        c = Compass(*args)
        print(c.coordX + ' ' + c.coordY + ' ' + c.coordZ + ' ' + c.posit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion also solves the problem without instantiating more objects.